# Extra/dupe members in SOAP response prevents serialization (Axis, Java, Gson)

Tags: java, json, wsdl, axis, gson

I am using Axis to call a SOAP-based web service. I'm then trying to serialize the returned remote object as JSON, using the Google Gson library.

The serialization to JSON fails, with Gson complaining that "there are multiple elements with the name __equalsCalc()).

When I inspect the returned object in my IDE (Eclipse), I can see that this is true -- the returned object has three members called __equalsCalc() and another three called __hashCode.

I know from looking around that these are added by WSDL2Java (I think) in order to avoid recursion. My question is, why are there THREE of each? And how can I get the serializer to ignore these? They're not actually part of the object's definition (it's called a RemoteProject, for reference). Can I do something hackish like cast the RemoteProject to a RemoteProject to get it to drop those members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be not too hard to solve. I have multiple copies of the same instance var because the class being serialized is shadowing fields of the same name from superclasses. Since I don't care about these fields, the best approach in Gson is to write a custom ExckusionStrategy which can selectively ignore fields based on their name:

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GSon. 
With [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), you can annotate properties (i.e - fields that have getters/setters according to Java bean convention) with @JsonIgnore. 
This way you can prevent issues like recursion/no matching setter or getter and so on... 
Try to find out if you have the same at GSon or use Jackson.

Comment: Gson will ignore fields marked "transient." The problem is that the class definitions themselves are auto-generated, by Axis, so if start editing those to mark fields transient, it gets ugly. I may need to write some sort of custom deserializer for Gson ....

Comment: @SteveLane - I guess you do, this is also a valid solution in case of Jackson. However, when I worked with Axis (something like 5 years ago) I don't remember I had these auto generated methods. Maybe things have changed since...