# Serialize an object to json in Java?

Tags: java, json, struts2, gson

I am trying to serialize an instance of Campaign in Adwords API with gson at first with the code below:

```
Campaign c = new Campaign(); 
c.setName("beijing");
c.setId(23423L);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(c);
```

and I get the exception that  class Money declares multiple JSON fields named __equalsCalc. When I try to serialize the instance with json plugin of struts2 with the code below

```
String str = org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(c);
System.out.println(str);
```

It works and output the correct result

```
{"adServingOptimizationStatus":null,"biddingStrategy":null,"budget":null,"campaignStats":null,"conversionOptimizerEligibility":null,"endDate":null,"frequencyCap":null,"id":23423,"name":"beijing","networkSetting":null,"servingStatus":null,"settings":null,"startDate":null,"status":null}
```

Then my question is that why can the json plugin of struts2 can serialize the instance correctly while gson cannot? Can I use the json plugin of struts2 to serialize objects to json since it is design to produce json result in struts2 not for this situation.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297591/extra-dupe-members-in-soap-response-prevents-serialization-axis-java-gson

Comment: The plugin can do it as it's part of the culprit (I guess struts2 generates those crazy fields, so it also knows there are to be ignored). See the accepted answer in the duplicate question. @sundar: Surely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json` plugin in struts2 to serialize your object manually to `json` string. You can do that by calling the `serialize` static method.

```
String jsonString = JSONUtil.serialize(your_object);
```

Don't forget to include `xwork-core` jar in your classpath because it depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either a bug in Gson or it is more particular/less robust. Without looking at the code for either it would be hard to know more.

Personally I use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for JSON to POJO transformations.

Ultimately as long as the Structs2 plugin is available on your classpath I don't see why you couldn't leverage it's classes to handle JSON transformations. Ultimately JSON is a format therefore all JSON libraries need to produce commonly understandable data.

Comment: -1 This is by no means a bug in Gson. There are those fields and they create a conflict preventing the default serialization.

Comment: fair enough, I did not have the classes in an IDE to inspect actual behaviour. I did not intend to insult Gson and did not understand that struts was being utilized by the API (my interpretation was that it had no more significant usage here than that as an alternative JSON deserializer).

Comment: @maaartinus do you know how to make overriding fields possible to use with gson?

Comment: @Mathew: I don't know how to do it in general, but using `ExclusionStrategy` should work; just exclude them all if you don't need them. Or use `FieldNamingStrategy` to resolve the conflict.

Comment: `FieldNamingStrategy` does not help when there is field overriding. GSON thows exceptions in such situation anyway. I will try ExclusionStrategy next time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by moving my use of SimpleDateFormat from the class level to inside a method.  GSON doesn't have to serialize SimpleDateFormat this way.

Hope this helps someone - 45 minutes of head banging for me!  :-)